# Deploying an App to Azure - avoid first hit performance problems

Tags: azure, deployment, web-applications

I want to know if there's a way to "precompile" my .net mvc web application before publishing it to an Azure Web app in order to avoid the huge performance hit when a page is accessed for the first time.

Also - if there is any web app configuration I should follow to avoid this problem (other than the "Always on" property), please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the auto-swap slots feature of Azure App Service.  With this method, you deploy to a staging slot.  The fabric will warm the application up and then automatically put it in production for you.

See [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/) for more details